# how to resize image and keep it proportional based on div thumbnail?

Tags: html, css

I have some images that I show on `div` thumbnail like images below. I want if I upload an image with different size, the image in thumbnail still shows with proportional size. Thanks for help.
[image: Example image]

```
<div class="col-md-4 product simpleCart_shelfItem text-center" style="height:500px;">
  <a href="?page=detail&id=<?php echo $r['idbarang']?>&id2=<?php echo $r['idstok']?>">

    <!--img src="admin/<?php echo $r['gambar']?>" width="394" height="480" alt="" /-->
    <img src="admin/<?php echo $r['gambar']?>" height="450" alt="" />
  </a>
  <?php if ( $r['diskon'] != '' && $r['diskon'] != '0' ) { ?>
    <a href="?page=detail&id=<?php echo $r['idbarang']?>&id2=<?php echo $r['idstok']?>">
      <div class="offer3">

        <span class="badge">
          <span class="badge">
            <span class="badge"><?php echo  "Sale "."$r[diskon]"."%" ?>
            </span>
          </span>
        </span>

      </div>
    <?php } ?>


    <div class="mask">
      <a href="?page=detail&id=<?php echo $r['idbarang']?>&id2=<?php echo $r['idstok']?>">Quick View</a>
    </div>
    <a class="product_name" href="?page=detail&id=<?php echo $r['idbarang']?>&id2=<?php echo $r['idstok']?>">
      <?php echo $r['namabarang']?>
    </a>
    <?php if ( $r['diskon'] == ''  ) { ?>
      <p> <span class="item_price"> <?php echo $harga ?></span></a></p>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if ( $r['diskon'] == '0'  ) { ?>
      <p> <span class="item_price"> <?php echo $harga ?></span></a></p>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php if ( $r['diskon'] != '' && $r['diskon'] != '0') { ?>
      <p> <font face="comic sans ms" color="brown" size="2"><strike> <?php echo $harga ?></strike></font></p>
        &nbsp; <p><span class="item_price"> <?php echo $diskon ?></span></p>
      </span></a></p>
    <?php } ?>

  </div>
```

Comment: if you can provide working code with CSS it will be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to place any size image onto the page and have it appear the same size you can ensure that an image fits it's parent element's size with the CSS property object-fit 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/